# How to open onepkg file in Windows Phone 8 using C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, onenote, windows-phone-8-emulator

Is there any way to open .onepkg file in Windows Phone 8 using C# code?

I tried using

```
string imageFile = @"File.onepkg";
var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(imageFile);
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
```

This is a default launcher for launching apps in the phone.

I have OneNote installed (It works perfectly fine and opens OneNote in windows phone emulator when i change the extension from .onepkg to .one).

But if it is a OneNote notebook, instead of opening OneNote it looks in windows phone store and when I say *"I accept"*, it shows *"No apps found"*.

Can anyone please give me any pointers/suggestions?

Comment: No need to make all the text bold.

Comment: Changed the text... Coming to the question any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the `<Extensions>` element of the WP8 Onenote app it seems only *.one and *.onetoc2 file extensions are supported in the current version. That makes sense connsidering *.onepkg files are templates to create new files but app2app file extension support is currently limited to read-only scenarios.

```
  <Extensions>
    <FileTypeAssociation
      Name="OneNote file"
      TaskID="Default"
      NavUriFragment="CmdLine=-s &quot;token:%s&quot;">
      <Logos>
        <Logo Size="small" IsRelative="true">OneNoteFileIcon.small.{ScreenResolution}.png</Logo>
        <Logo Size="medium" IsRelative="true">OneNoteFileIcon.medium.{ScreenResolution}.png</Logo>
        <Logo Size="large" IsRelative="true">OneNoteFileIcon.large.{ScreenResolution}.png</Logo>
      </Logos>
      <SupportedFileTypes>
        <FileType ContentType="application/onenote">.one</FileType>
      </SupportedFileTypes>
    </FileTypeAssociation>
    <FileTypeAssociation
      Name="OneNote notebook"
      TaskID="Default"
      NavUriFragment="CmdLine=-s &quot;token:%s&quot;">
      <Logos>
        <Logo Size="small" IsRelative="true">OneNoteNoteBookIcon.small.{ScreenResolution}.png</Logo>
        <Logo Size="medium" IsRelative="true">OneNoteNoteBookIcon.medium.{ScreenResolution}.png</Logo>
        <Logo Size="large" IsRelative="true">OneNoteNoteBookIcon.large.{ScreenResolution}.png</Logo>
      </Logos>
      <SupportedFileTypes>
        <FileType ContentType="application/onenote">.onetoc2</FileType>
      </SupportedFileTypes>
    </FileTypeAssociation>
    <Protocol
      Name="onenote"
      TaskID="Default"
      NavUriFragment="CmdLine=-u &quot;%s&quot;"/>
  </Extensions>
```

Comment: So should i uncompress the .one and .onetoc2 files in windows phone 8. How do you achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I think onepkg is a zip file containing .one and .onetoc files along with directory structure.
So one way could be to expand this cab file and then open it.

Type: Cab

Method: LZX

Blocks: 1

Volumes: 1

Comment: Can you suggest or guide me on how to achieve this?